# multiple BLE devices which have same services and characteristics in ios

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I have multiple BLE devices which have same services and characteristics. I can scan and connect multiple devices. After connections, when I try to distinguish each one by sending command it doesn't work. It works perfectly with a single device. Is it something like socket connection ? Like A server spawns child threads and each client can maintain a connection through threads.

Please provide some tips on how to scan each device when other device is reading the data from the device.

```
-(void) scanDevice {

  centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

  [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:0];

 [AppDelegate app].cbCentral = centralManager;

}

-(void) stopScan {

    [[AppDelegate app].cbCentral stopScan];
}

-(void)connectToDevice:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral{


  [[AppDelegate app] cbCentral].delegate = self;
  [[[AppDelegate app] cbCentral] connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];

}

 -(void)calldiscoverServicesForPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral{

  [peripheral setDelegate:self];
  [peripheral discoverServices:nil];

}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral     *)peripheral {

NSLog(@"Connected PERIPHERAL %d",peripheral.state);

  [delegate getConnectedPeripheral:peripheral];

  NSLog(@"Connected peripheral %@",peripheral);
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error {

   NSLog(@"Discovered servicea: %@", peripheral.services);

  for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
    NSLog(@"Discovered service: %@", [service.UUID data]);
    [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];
  }
}
```

I will explain in detail,

I have table view, that contains BLE devices. For the first time it is empty, so i will search for the devices by calling a class "Scan Devices".

This "Scan devices" class contains all the Corebluetooth methods like CBCentralManager allocation, CBperipheral delegate methods.

After search, I will display the device in table view and connect to the BLE device. I am getting some data from "Scan Device" class.

Now, I want to search more devices to connect and get the data. For this, I will call [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self] in "ScanDevices" class. At this time, for previous device(connected and reading) is showing the warning "is not a valid peripheral" and new device is connecting and reading data from the device.

But I want read the data from both devices at a time

Please help me...
Thanks

Comment: You should send read and write requests to the specific CBPeripheral object. Can you show that code?

Comment: PLease check the question, i have edited the question for code.

Comment: Which line gives you the warning?  What does `[delegate getConnectedPeripheral:]` do? Are you reading or notifying on the characteristic?  Where do you do that?

Comment: I am calling these methods from viewcontroller, when the available devices return from core bluetooth, then I am creating my own [delegate getConnectedPeripheral:]  from this scan class to viewcontroller.

Comment: And also, I am able to connect to one device and getting the data in didDiscoverCharacteristics. But, While reading the data, I will search for the devices again for that I will call Scanperipherals, at that time coreblutooth is giving warning "is not valid peripheral".

Comment: It sounds like you are possibly overwriting a variable that is holding your connected peripheral. In your getConnectedPeripheral method do you store the peripheral in an array? It would also be more efficient to scan for peripheral offering your known service rather than nil. There is no reason why you cannot continue to scan for peripherals while connected. You need to identify the specific line that is causing the invalid peripheral message

Comment: Could you please check the edited question, I explained in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't keep creating a new CBCentral - doing so will cause your previous CBCentral to be deallocated and therefore invalidate the existing peripherals.

You should activate your scanning once, say in `viewWillAppear` and deactivate it in `viewWillDisappear`.

Once you have initiated scanning and set your delegate in your `ScanDevices` class, it will call `[delegate getConnectedPeripheral:]` each time a new peripheral is found and connected.